# Como Serializar mais dados de mais de uma tabela em django rest-framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-2.0, django-rest-framework

Fala Povo!
Estou o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma tabela de compra e venda:

```py
class SalesOrBuy(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mode   = models.IntegerField(choices = [(0,'VENDA'), (1,'COMPRA')])
    status = models.IntegerField(choices = STATUS_CHOICES, default='PENDENTE')
    date   = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    off   = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, default=0, decimal_places=2)
```

e uma de Itens de Carrinho que recebem o Pk(sbid) das Compra e vendas como Forenig Key:

```py
class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    qtd = models.IntegerField( default=0, validators=[ MinValueValidator(0) ] )
    sbid = models.ForeignKey(SalesOrBuy, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    svid = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    op_type = models.IntegerField(choices = [(0,'COMPVEND'), (1,'ITEM'), (2,'MATERIAL')], default=0)
```

Agora estou tentando criar uma api Rest com o Django-Restframework, mas para reduzir o numero de requests gostaria de passar apenas um json contendo as informações da tabela de SalesOrBuy quanto da tabela CartItem da seguinte forma:

```js
{
    "client": 1,
    "mode": 1,
    "status": 0,
    "date": "2019-04-07",
    "off": "1.11",
    "amount": "6.00",
    "cart":[[1,5],[3,2]]
}
```

onde o "cart" seria uma lista de lista contendo o id do produto e a quantidade do mesmo.

Vi pela Doc do Framework e consegui fazer o CRUD tradicional de ambas as tabelas:

**serializers.py**

```py
class SaleOrBuySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SalesOrBuy
        fields = [
            'client',
            'mode',
            'status',
            'date',
            'off',
            'amount'
        ]



class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SalesOrBuy
        fields = [
            'product',
            'qtd',
            'sbid',
            'svid',
            'op_type',
        ]
```

**views.py**

```py
class SaleOrBuyListView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = SaleOrBuySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SalesOrBuy.objects.all()


class SaleOrBuyRudView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    serializer_class = SaleOrBuySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SalesOrBuy.objects.all()
```

só que desta forma eu teria que fazer muitas requests para montar os dados no frontend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro da um nome para o seu ralacionamento para ficar mais fácil de entender:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    qtd = models.IntegerField( default=0, validators=[ MinValueValidator(0) ] )
    sbid = models.ForeignKey(SalesOrBuy, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cart")
    svid = models.ForeignKey(Service, null=True, blank=True ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    op_type = models.IntegerField(choices = [(0,'COMPVEND'), (1,'ITEM'), (2,'MATERIAL')], default=0)
```

Você vai precisa criar um Serializer de `Product`. Depois fazer os viculos da seguinte forma:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SalesOrBuy
        fields = [
            'product',
            'qtd',
            'sbid',
            'svid',
            'op_type',
        ]

class SaleOrBuySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    cart = CartItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SalesOrBuy
        fields = [
            'client',
            'mode',
            'status',
            'date',
            'off',
            'amount',
            "cart" # Nome do relacionamento que vc deu no model
        ]
```

Referencia para estudos [aqui](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).